# Standing Point Of Exponential Function Combined With Polynomial

Tags: optimization

How to Find Minimum Of the below function using Calculus Method?

$$f(x)=(x-2)e^{x-2}-(x+3)^2$$

After Differentiating Once, the equation turns out to be:

$$f '(x)= -2e^{x-2} + 2x.e^{x-2} - 2x -6.$$

From this step to find the minimum, we need to find the zeros of $f '(x)$. But how to find the zeros of the equation $f '(x)$ with exponentials and polynomial combined together? Should I Use Logarithm to find zeros of such equations?

Though we can find the minimum using Numerical methods, I am interested in Knowing the Calculus way of solving This.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, Sir, I have Edited As per standards. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @VKJ would you fix your derivative? It is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you search for the minimum of function
$$f(x)=(x-2)e^{x-2}-(x+3)^2$$
$$f'(x)=e^{x-2} (x-1)-2 (x+3)=0 \implies e^{x-2}=2\,\frac{x+3 } {x-1 }$$
Make $x-2=-t$ to get
$$e^{-t}=2\,\frac{ t-5}{t-1}$$ Have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) and in particular at equation $(4)$. The solution is "just" given in terms of the generalized Lambert function.

From a practical point of view, you will need some numerical method.